# Is there a Server Side Javascript engine for IIS?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, iis, serverside-javascript

I am looking for a solution similar to Aptana's Jaxer where I can execute javascript server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://nodejs.org/.

It uses the V8 Engine which is the fastest javascript engine.

Comment: iisnode has made some amazing strides :) I've been using it alongside an MVC ASP.NET app (although you can use it by itself).

Answer (score 5):

You have ASP JScript which works on IIS on the server-side. Its almost like standard JavaScript.

Comment: IIS has been running server-side JScript - which is a compliant implementation of ECMAScript - since the Windows NT 4 Option Pack, sometime around 1998...