# javascript execution from c#

Tags: c#, javascript

window.execscript("mycode","javascript") is not working when tried to execute,also not giving any exception at that point.Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, your question does not contain much detail and it will be hard to answer unless you can provide some more context.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in running JavaScript on the server, then see this related question [Execute javascript on IIS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719748/execute-javascript-on-iis-server)

Answer (score 0):

You know we can't execute javascript from code behind at server side. What we can do is to register a java script and make it run after the page is rendered at client side. Here is an example:

```
//Page_Load method in Default.aspx.cs, notepad code
string js = "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('hello world!'); </script>";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"helloworld",js);
```

Here I use a string directly, usually you can generate a complex javascript with StringBuilder. RegisterStartupScript will add the js to the page and execute it when the script is loaded.